# Simplify a javascript for range sliders

Tags: javascript, slider

I am new to coding.  I have gotten my code to work like I want it, but the javascript is alittle long.  How would I go about simplifing the script?  Can some one point me to a tutorial on how to do this.

I know I am making this more complicated then it needs to be by writting it all out instead of simplifing the code.

Thanks

See the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1ovdnLch/)

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");

output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}

var slider1 = document.getElementById("myRange1");
var output1 = document.getElementById("demo1");

output1.innerHTML = slider1.value;

slider1.oninput = function() {
  output1.innerHTML = this.value;
}

var slider2 = document.getElementById("myRange2");
var output2 = document.getElementById("demo2");

output2.innerHTML = slider2.value;

slider2.oninput = function() {
  output2.innerHTML = this.value;
}

var slider3 = document.getElementById("myRange3");
var output3 = document.getElementById("demo3");

output3.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider3.oninput = function() {
  output3.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Do you have any issue or error in particular? If not you may get better results if you post your question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: There was no error, I just thought the code was too long.  It worked but I was looking to how to shorten it down instead of writing it all out.  Thanks for the link to Code review, did not know about that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option:

```
function initSlider(suffix) {
  var slider = document.getElementById('myRange' + suffix);
  var output = document.getElementById('demo' + suffix);

  output.innerHTML = slider.value;

  slider.oninput = function() {
    output.innerHTML = this.value;
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  var suffix = i == 0 ? '' : i;
  initSlider(suffix);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Danil, this helped me alot.